# Migration from Spring 3.2 to Spring 4.3

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

How can I migrate my application from Spring 3.2 to 4.3?

No maven used.
No hibernate used.

What jars would be required?
What changes I would have to make in web.xml and appContext.xml and others files?

Can please anybody help with step-wise?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This should help: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-4.x.

Comment: Why do you want to upgrade from one old version to another old version? The current release version of Spring is `5.0.6`.